# Raspberry Pi, Docker, & Pandas Challenge

Tags: python, pandas, docker, raspberry-pi3

I am struggling to create a docker container that has pandas for my raspberry pi. Has anyone done this successfully and able to share how they got it to work?

Below is my dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM arm32v7/python:3.7

# Install system dependencies for Pandas
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        python3-dev \
        libatlas-base-dev \
        gfortran \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Pandas and NumPy
RUN pip install pandas numpy

# Commands to run within the container (not needed for this example)
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: What is the problem you have with the container?

Comment: The build does not complete/freezes. Or, it abends and gives me an error message. I've installed a fresh version of Raspberry Pi OS.  I've tried many versions of this. I can get numpy to be installed, but have not yet figured out how to get pandas too.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: I tried running it a few times yesterday/overnight and while I am not getting error messages now, it is not completing.